# How is TRUE interpreted when used as matrix index?

Tags: r

I saw some (bad) code somewhere  which turned out to call a function which executed `mymatrix[TRUE]` along the way.  It turns out, at least in the samples I tested, that this is interpreted as selecting all elements of the matrix. Clearly `[` is not coercing `TRUE` to `1`, because then I'd get only the first element returned, not the entire matrix.
 `mymatrix[FALSE]` returns `numeric(0)` .
Can someone explain what `[` is actually doing here?

Comment: When used as indices, Logical vectors are recycled to match the length of the vector. `mymatrix[c(TRUE, FALSE)]` would give you every other element.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde: post as answer ... ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Logical` indices tell `R` which elements to include or exclude.

You have three options:

```
TRUE, FALSE, NA
```

They serve to indicate whether or not the index represented in that position should be included. 
In other words:

```
  TRUE  == "Include the elment at this index"
  FALSE == "Do not include the element at this index"
  NA    == "Return NA instead of this index"  _(losely speaking)_
```

For example:

```
x <- 1:6
x[ c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, NA, TRUE, FALSE)]
#  [1]  1  3 NA  5
```

However, standard recycling rules apply. So in the previous example, if we drop the last `FALSE`, 
the index vector is recylced, the first element of the index is `TRUE`, and hence the `6`th element of `x` is now included

```
x <- 1:6
x[ c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, NA, TRUE       )]
#  [1]  1  3 NA  5  6
```

#### Multi dimensional `x`

The above holds for any object that can be subseted using `[`, not just vectors.

If `x` is multidimensional, we can use logical indecies on one orr all of the dimensions, or even a logical matrix as an matrix-index.

```
x <- matrix(1:12, nrow=3, ncol=4)

# using logical vectors on both dims
#   returns intersection of 2nd row and 3rd column
x[c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE),  c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)]
# [1] 7

# Same value
x[c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE),  3]
# [1] 7

# return a checkerboard pattern, using a logical matrix as an index
x[ matrix(c(TRUE, FALSE), nrow=3, ncol=4) ]
```

#### Single dimension indexing of a multi-dimensional object.

The catch is that matricies can be indexed not only by their dimensions, but also by their specific elements:

```
x[7]
# [1] 7
```

Combining this fact, with `R`'s recycling rules, we get the result referenced in the OP.
That is,  `x[TRUE]` is the equivalent of `x[ rep(TRUE, length(x)) ]`, which is the 
equivalent of `return every element of x`

```
x[TRUE]
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12

x[TRUE, ,drop=FALSE]
#        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    4    7   10
# [2,]    2    5    8   11
# [3,]    3    6    9   12
```

Comment: Great detail, tho' I can't resist suggesting that classifying `NA` as boolean is dangerously close to  thedailywtf's meme that the boolean set consists of `c(TRUE, FALSE, NA, File_Not_Found)` :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, you are absolutely correct.  I originally had written `logical` and changed it to `boolean`.  I will change it back

Answer (score 7):

When used as indices, logical vectors are recycled to match the length of the vector. For example, `mymatrix[c(TRUE, FALSE)]` would give you every other element.