# Why does x[NA] yield an NA vector the same length as x?

Tags: r

The code is like this

```
x <- 1:5
x[NA]
```

Why does it produce 5 NAs?

Comment: Good question. Try to answer yourself by seeing what `x[TRUE]`, `x[FALSE]`, `class(NA)` and `x[NA_integer_]` return.

Comment: `x[c(NA,TRUE)]` might also be enlightening, in that it shows explicitly the vector recycling both an `NA` and non-`NA` value.

Comment: See similar posts [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23406124/na-in-subsetter-inconsistent-behavior) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16418689/how-is-true-interpreted-when-used-as-matrix-index)

Comment: Why was this given a bounty?

Answer (score 13):

The answer to this question has two sides:

**How is NA interpreted when indexing matrices?**

In [one of the links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16418689/how-is-true-interpreted-when-used-as-matrix-index)  provided by @alexis_laz, I found a very well structured explanation of how `TRUE`, `FALSE` and `NA` are interpreted when indexing matrices:

> `Logical` indices tell `R` which elements to include or exclude.
>
> You have three options: `TRUE`, `FALSE` and `NA`
>
> They serve to indicate whether or not the index represented in that position  should be included. In other words:
>
> ```
> TRUE  == "Include the elment at this index"
> FALSE == "Do not include the element at this index"
> NA    == "Return NA instead of this index" #  loosely speaking
> ```
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> x <- 1:6
> x[ c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, NA, TRUE, FALSE)]
> # [1]  1  3 NA  5
> ```

An important detail is that the default storage mode for an isolated `NA` value is logical (try `typeof(NA)`).  You can choose the storage mode of the `NA` by using `NA_integer_`, `NA_real_` (for double), `NA_complex_` or `NA_character_`.

**Why 5 `NA` and not just 1?**

When the length of the indices is smaller than the length of vector `x`, the indexing will start over to also index the values in `x` that have not been indexed yet. In other words, `R` will automatically "recycle" the indices:

> (...) However, standard recycling rules apply. So in the previous example, if we drop the last `FALSE`, the index vector is recycled, the first element of the index is `TRUE`, and hence the 6th element of `x` is now included
>
> ```
> x <- 1:6
> x[c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, NA, TRUE)]
> #  [1]  1  3 NA  5  6
> ```

Recall the detail about the storage mode from the previous section.  If you type `x[NA_integer_]`, then you will find a different result.

Comment: What new info does this add to the answer in the 2nd link provide by alexis_laz?

Comment: It doesn't add any info. The question was awaiting an answer and I put together the info provided in the comments